# ResultSet is not scrolling

Tags: java, jdbc

Please have a look at the following code

```
public List searchData(String query)
    {
        List data = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
             createConnection();

             Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);


                while(rs.next())
                {

                 data.add(rs.getString(2));
                 data.add(rs.getString(11));
                 data.add(rs.getString(12));
                 data.add(rs.getInt(3));
                 data.add(rs.getInt(4));
                 data.add(rs.getInt(5));
                 data.add(rs.getInt(6));
                 data.add(rs.getString(7));
                 data.add(rs.getString(8));
                 data.add(rs.getString(9));
                 data.add(rs.getString(10));

                }


                for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(data.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("Size of the array: "+data.size());



        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        }
}
```

This code is giving the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataInteger(JdbcOdbc.java:3810)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataInteger(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5637)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:582)
    at normal.DatabaseHandler.searchData(DatabaseHandler.java:331)
    at normal.SearchForm$ButtonAction.actionPerformed(SearchForm.java:470)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Why is this? If I put the

```
data.add(rs.getString(11));
data.add(rs.getString(12));
```

at the end, this error is not happening. I have even set the result set to be scrollable! Why is this? Please help!

Comment: Do not use numbers as indexes. Always use the column names when retreiving data from a resultset. This will make it easier to make modifications on the table without affecting your existing code.

Comment: That is not the issue. I did it now. No good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"scrolling" a result set has to do with moving backwards and forwards among *different rows*.  you are having an issue with getting the column values for a *given row*.  some jdbc drivers are sensitive to the column order, and i don't think that's a settings thing.  i would say you either need to read the columns in order, or possibly look for a different jdbc driver.

Comment: awesome..Yes, I was doing all those inside "while(rs.next())", which checks for the same raw, and keep moving forward. I decided to take all those data into seperate variables, then do whatever I need. Thanks a lot for the reply :)